# How to sum same column of different data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 4 dataframes and each of them has exactly same number of rows and columns. The values in Column 1,2,5 are same in each data frame. From those 4 dataframes, I want to obtain a single dataframe where the third and fourth columns ('pred1' and 'pred2') are created by summing the values in the 4 dataframes. Is it possible to do that ? here is my dataframes:

```
df1  = read.csv(fname1,header=FALSE,col.names=c("c1", "c2", "pred1", "pred2","c5")))
df2  = read.csv(fname2,header=FALSE,col.names=c("c1", "c2", "pred1", "pred2","c5")))
df3  = read.csv(fname3,header=FALSE,col.names=c("c1", "c2", "pred1", "pred2","c5")))
df4  = read.csv(fname4,header=FALSE,col.names=c("c1", "c2", "pred1", "pred2","c5")))
```

Comment: R so not `pandas`?

Comment: what do you mean summing the values in the 4 data frames?  Are you adding c1, c2, c5?

Comment: Remove pandas . Since not related to pandas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
df5 <- df1
df5$pred1 <- df1$pred1 + df2$pred1 + df3$pred1 + df4$pred1
df5$pred2 <- df1$pred2 + df2$pred2 + df3$pred2 + df4$pred2
```

Based on Gregor's suggestions, you could also create a vector to store the columns to be added (in case there are a lot), and then add those together as with

```
cols = c("pred1", "pred2")
df5[, cols] = df1[, cols] + df2[, cols] + df3[, cols] + df4[, cols]
```

akrun also provides a suggestion which I don't follow, but seems like it would work well with arbitrarily many dataframes as well (just expand 1:4 to 1:n, where n is the number of the last df).

```
Reduce("+", lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:4)), "[[", c("pred1", "pred2")))
```

Comment: Place it in a `list` i.e. `Reduce("+", lapply(mget(paste0('df", 1:4)), "[[", c("pred1", "pred2")))`

Comment: This looks really clever, but also beyond my ability to parse. Maybe you should make it another answer?

Comment: It's quick and fine answer, but it won't scale up for more columns or more data frames. Akrun's comment show you how to scale up both. A half-way-there medium is this, which saves a little typing and would let you scale up the columns easily: `cols = c("pred1", "pred2")`, then `df5[, cols] = df1[, cols] + df2[, cols] + df3[, cols] + df4[, cols]`

Comment: Thanks, I added both suggestions. Yours is much clearer to me, and will obviously work a lot better with many columns to be added. akrun's is still beyond me, but I included it because I see the advantage of being able to work with lots of dfs at once.

Comment: Annotated version of Akrun's answer: `paste0('df', 1:4)` creates the names of the existing data frames as strings, and `mget` gets the objects with those names and puts them in a list. In a better world, OP's data would already be in a list, so the `mget(paste(...))` would be replaced with `my_list`. The `lapply` extracts the specified columns from each df in the list, and then `Reduce("+", ...)` adds them together.

Answer (score -1):

If df1, d2, df3, and df 4 have the same values when you merge them
you will get df5 that will the df1 values and the size of df1 
than why don't you just

```
          df5 <- df1
          df5$Pred1 <- rowSums(df1)
          df5$pred2 <- rowSums(df5[,1:4])
```

First, you should merge all the df and then just create a new Columns pred1 and pred2

```
     df1 <- data.frame(c1= c(1,1,2,2,4),c2 = c(2,2,3,3,5),c5 = c(3,4,4,5,6))
     df2 <- data.frame(c1= c(10,1,2,2,4),c2 = c(2,2,30,3,5),c5 = c(3,4,40,5,6))
     df3 <- data.frame(c1= c(15,1,2,2,4),c2 = c(22,2,3,3,5),c5 = c(3,44,4,5,6))
     df4 <- data.frame(c1= c(12,1,2,2,4),c2 = c(2,23,3,3,5),c5 = c(3,4,45,5,6))
     tmp <- merge(df1,df2,by= c("c1","c2","c5"),all.x = TRUE,all.y=TRUE)
     tmp <- merge(tmp,df3,by= c("c1","c2","c5"),all.x = TRUE,all.y=TRUE)
     tmp <- merge(tmp,df4,by= c("c1","c2","c5"),all.x = TRUE,all.y=TRUE)
     tmp$pred1 = rowSums(tmp[,1:3])
     tmp:

     tmp
        c1 c2 c5 pred1
        1   1  2  3     6
        2   1  2  4     7
        3   1  2 44    47
        4   1 23  4    28
        5   2  3  4     9
        ....
```